# How to label chapters/sections/remarks/etc. with symbols

Tags: sectioning

I am writing a thesis in report class, and I would like to have something like the following format.

Table of Contents

Part I: Introduction

Chapter 1: Some history

Chapter 2: Some literature

Chapter 3: Some more waffly stuff

Chapter $\spadesuit$: Statement of the main results

Part II: The meaty stuff

Chapter 4: Proof of Theorem $\spadesuit$.1

etc. etc.

Does anyone know how to create a chapter with sections labelled via a symbol, such as the $\spadesuit$ symbol, so Chapter $\spadesuit$ with Section $\spadesuit$.1, Section $\spadesuit$.2, etc. and Theorem $\spadesuit$.1 etc. and to have this chapter appear like that in the TOC?

Many thanks! A.

Comment: I am not sure what you need, but hope you may expect as `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.$\spadesuit$}`

Comment: I am afraid that running this just inserted spades all throughout my document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the way the chapter counter is printed (i.e., the `\thechapter` macro) within the special chapter, and restore it afterwards. Note that the counter itself is still numeric, so if you want to continue numbering following the previous normal chapter then you need to decrease the chapter counter by one.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{Some history}
\chapter{Some literature}
\chapter{Some more waffly stuff}

\let\theoldchapter\thechapter
\def\thechapter{$\spadesuit$}
\chapter{Statement of the main results}
\section{Result section}
\begin{theorem}
Waffles are tasty
\label{thm:waffles}
\end{theorem}
\let\thechapter\theoldchapter
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}

\part{The meaty stuff}
\chapter{Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:waffles}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work great :)